# Existence of a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis

I am interested is the following correct:

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and every $\sigma \in S_n$ (a permutation of $\{1,2,...,n\}$) there exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and a polynomial $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + ... + a_mx^m$ such that for every $1 \leq i \leq n$, $\sigma(i) = p(i)$.

If this is correct, I would love a proof of it, cause I can not think of how would I approach this and maybe if it is possible that $m \leq n$. For 2 variables (i.e. $n = 2$) you can always take a linear function. But I can not think of a proof in general, as induction does not seem to work to me. Any help and comment will be warmly welcomed.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation – For arbitrary numbers $\sigma(1), \ldots \sigma(n)$ there is a polynomial (of degree at most $n-1$) such that $p(i) = \sigma(i)$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$.

Comment: Thanks Martin, this also shows that indeed $m \leq n$... I thought this is possible only I did not know where do I know this from.